# Criar um form de login e senha no canto superior direito da tela

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de colocar um `form` de login e senha no canto superior direito da tela com a opcão de cadastrar.

```
<input type="text" name="nome">
<input type="password" name="senha">
<input type="button" value="Entrar" />
```

Comment: Você já deve ter algum código, certo?

Comment: Já experimentaste fazer uma div e dar-lhe posicionamento á direita? Coloca mais HTML para sabermos como a tua página é e darmos uma solução mais acertada.

Comment: **`texto em negrito`** foi a única coisa que eu entendi

Comment: tente este site com certeza você encontrará a solução http://bootsnipp.com/tags/login

Comment: Cria uma div em volta desses inputs e coloca `float: right;` nela usando o CSS. Lembrando que sua div tem que estar criada no topo do seu documento.

Answer (score 5):

Vê se ajuda.

```css
#nav{height:77px; width:100%;background: #f1f1f1;padding:7px;}
    #sup_direito{float:right; width:auto; }
        #login, #senha, #cadastrar{float:left;}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <div id="sup_direito">
    <div id="login"><input type="text" placeholder="login"></div>
    <div id="senha"><input type="password" placeholder="senha"></div>
    <div id="cadastrar"><a href="cadastrar.php">cadastrar</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```